# Обращение к переменной

Tags: переменные, java

Как я могу обратиться к  переменной из другого класс , которую я инкапсулировал , а после инкапсуляции через set предал ей значение ? Мне нужно "вытянуть" именно значение которое я предал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделай в довесок методу set для этой переменной метод get, который будет возвращать ссылку на эту переменную и вся недолга.

Comment: В том то и беда , что метод get уже сделан.И к тому же к этим методам обращается не один объект а много, а мне нужно все по отдельности отобразить в другом классе и найти их сумму(сумму тех значений которые я сам им же и присваивал)

Comment: Что-то я слабо въезжаю тогда, что нужно сделать. Код можно увидеть?

Comment: public class task {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassFish goldFish = new ClassFish();
        goldFish.setPrice(2);
        goldFish.setName("<<Золотая рыбка>>");
        goldFish.priceOfFish();
        ClassFish bigGoldFish = new ClassFish();
        bigGoldFish.setPrice(4);
        bigGoldFish.setName("<<Японская золотая рыбка>>");
        bigGoldFish.priceOfFish();
        ClassAmount amount = new ClassAmount();
        amount.amountOfAll();
и отдельно создан класс ClassFish в котором определены 2 переменные price и name . В ClassAmount я пытаюсь найти их сумму

Comment: public class ClassAmount {

    public double amount;

    public void amountOfAll() {
        amount =  ?  ;
        System.out.println("Общая сумма при покупке =" + amount);
    }

}
А где вопросительный знак , я не могу и не знаю как обратиться к переменным.

Comment: Вот оно как. Если исходить из вашего решения - остается только передать все объекты для которых будет считаться суммарная стоимость в массиве, как параметр метода: amountOfAll(ClassFish[] fishs) и в нём уже для каждого переданного в метод объекта вызывать метод getPrice() и суммировать.

Comment: Передавайте в метод amountOfAll список объектов ClassFish, которые вы создали, и собирайте значения через getPrice.

Comment: Спасибо,огромное!Я именно так и поступлю